# Sending intermediate data from service to controller using angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I'm using angular-file-upload available here: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload.
As you can see in the example furnished on the same page, file data is posted to backend from a controller using the directives made available.

When I implemented the code however I moved the file posting to a service as that would allow me to re-use the functionality & feels the correct way(disagree?). Everything works fine except that I'm unable to figure out how to send the data from the `.progress(function(evt)){}`... function that tracks file upload completion status to the controller and respectively echo it on the html page.

Using the `.then` I can get the final success response I guess but how about this progress data?

Am I missing something very simple here? How to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a longtime, here is how this would work.

Using the notify callback for the promise solves the problem. As I had stated earlier, I had moved the file upload code (based on this rep [enter link description here](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)) into the angular services and I was not able to get file upload progress. Since I was returning the promise from services, so I could only get the file completion.

the above git rep also has a

```
.progress(function(evt){ file_upload_percent=(parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)})
```

function that gives the file completion percentage. Using the promise notify here, we can return this intermediate value like this :

```
.progress(function(evt) {   file_upload_percent=(parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)); deferred.notify(file_upload_percent);})
```

later using notify callback from the promise return, we can access the file completion percentage.

```
.then(function(response){},function(){},function(update){$scope.file_upload_percent=update});
```

use $scope.file_upload_percent as you would wish to.